# How to Resolve Graphene Django Field with Dependency On Another Field

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

Is it possible to resolve two fields using the output of one field to generate the output of the other field? For example, I need to generate a refresh token with the access token, but I'm unsure how to get the access token in the refresh token resolver.

```
class Tokens(graphene.ObjectType):
    accessToken = graphene.String()
    refreshToken = graphene.String()

    def resolve_accessToken(self, info, **kwargs):
        return "..."

    def resolve_refreshToken(self, info, **kwargs):
        return "..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a method to generate the access token that is called from the refresh methods

```
class Tokens(graphene.ObjectType):
    access_token = graphene.String()
    refresh_token = graphene.String()

    def get_access_token(self, info, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, '_access_token'):
            # Do stuff to create access token, then stash to only create once
            self._access_token = ...
        return self._access_token

    def resolve_access_token(self, info, **kwargs):
        return self.get_access_token(info, **kwargs)

    def resolve_refresh_token(self, info, **kwargs):
        access_token = self.get_access_token(info, **kwargs)
        # Do stuff to create and return refresh token ...
```

Also, you should call your methods and fields with snake case, i.e. `access_token` vs. `accessToken`