# How to use the result of a graphene resolved field in another field

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have this use case:

```py
class ProjectType(graphene.objectType):

  tasks = graphene.List(TaskType)
  duration = graphene.Int() # days

  def resolve_tasks():
    return self.tasks.all()
  
  def resolve_duration():
    return get_duration_from_tasks(self.tasks.all())
```

A project can have many tasks, so `self.tasks.all()` can be an expensive db query to do twice.

Comment: See the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833503/how-to-resolve-graphene-django-field-with-dependency-on-another-field/51866107#51866107